# Adding Aviary In-App Purchases iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, storekit, aviary

So I have tried to add Aviary's IAP purchases and have had little luck getting them to show up in my application. I have not made sure that following has happening

1. My Provisioning Profile being used to build the application has IAP's turned on
2. I have uploaded all of Aviary's IAP's to itunes connect
3. I have added the required code for IAP's in my app delegate:

   [[AFPhotoEditorController inAppPurchaseManager] startObservingTransactions];
   [AFPhotoEditorCustomization enableInAppPurchases:@YES];
4. Before I start my photo editor session I add the following code

   AFPhotoEditorController* photoEditor = [[AFPhotoEditorController alloc] initWithImage:imgToBeEdited];
   [AFPhotoEditorCustomization enableInAppPurchases:@YES];
   mPhotoEditorSession = [photoEditor session];
   editorController = photoEditor;
   [photoEditor setDelegate:self];

They are not showing up at all and I am uncertain of what Aviary is taking care of and what I should be taking care of

I think it might have to do with this line in the documentation:

Add the following lines to your app delegate's -applicationFinishedLaunchingWithOptions: method **before invoking any StoreKit framework methods**:

[[AFPhotoEditorController inAppPurchaseManager] startObservingTransactions];
This line adds the in-app purchase manager singleton as an **observer of the StoreKit payment queue returned by [SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]**, and sets a flag enabling in-app purchase code throughout the SDK.

Has anyone added this to their application and let me know what Storekit methods I need to invoke? Any sample code is helpful.

thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm running into similar issues, specifically on this method: [queue finishTransaction:transaction];